# My network accessing someone else's router

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I am using tp-link wi-fi router, however when I open the router settings I am getting router settings of someone else's Tenda wifi router.

How is that possible? It is also showing detials of that wifi router. Its SSID,  password, the devices attached to that device, the username of ISP, almost everything without loging into that router settings.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to your router and not on the Tenda that has no protection to it's administration page? Do you try to connect to the router using a cable?

Comment: I do not have any other router in my home and I am connected to my own router through WiFi.

Comment: When you enter the IP address of your router into your browser and when you are connected, is it a tp link interface or?

Comment: It is completely Tenda interface.
And now the problem has a little change in it since I posted it. Now the IP adress is inaccessible and shows the Connection Timeout error and the original tp-link interface is now showing up on the domain of the router settings (tplinklogin.net). 
I can simply reset the router but since I am a tech student i want to know the problem from root. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Like I said before, you where accessing your 'neighbor's' router that has the same IP address to access the administration page that your router has, and that isn't protected. I recommend connecting to your router using a cable for configuration purposes.

Comment: Is the IP address of your router 192.168.0.1?  If so, it's the same address as the Tenda's.

Comment: Is my explanation clear to you? If not, I'll be glad to answer any questions you may have.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to access neighbor's router, however I am connected to my own router. I said before that almost all the settings are of Tenda's router but not all the settings; the ISP password that was shown in Tenda's settings was actually my WiFi password. Moreover, Tenda router was not my neighbor's router but the location of the router is approx. 2 miles away from my home as shown by its SSID.

Comment: This is probably what happened : you were connected to a wifi network (most likely on the not secure Tenda 's wifi connection). When you tried accessing the administration interface of' the ' router' you got on the Tenda admin interface because you were connected to it via wifi. That's why you saw the Tenda's admin interface in your browser. Tenda and tp-link (most of the devices) have the same IP address and standard admin username and password. (be sure to change that on your router to prevent unauthorized access to your router 's configuration). At some point, you got disconnected from the

Comment: My comment was to long so it is not complete. I suggested to discuss this further in a chat but you don't have that privilege yet. 

Comment: I'm going to switch from smartphone to my computer so that it's easier for me to type messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95532/discussion-between-dakta-moriame-and-muhammad-jawad-khalil).

Comment: I started a chat to discuss this further, do you see/are you able to chat?

Comment: I just read that 20 rep. points are necessary to talk in chat.
That’s not your case right now. :-(
I’m going to write down (in a text file) all the explanations I want to send you, and I’ll post it once done.